# It is possible to run both IIS and Apache servers together for same application on linux?

Tags: linux, apache, iis, webserver

here is a brief what I am trying to achieve.

I am working with an application which is in WordPress and running on Apache and in one of the screen (page) it's require to use any already built module which has a large set of functionality built in .Net, that require an IIS support.

I am running WordPress application on Linux and not sure if Linux provide that flexibility to run both servers Apache and IIS at the same time.

Have gone through with some blogs but nothing yet, not sure even it's possible or not.

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: IIS does not run on Linux, period, but you can run asp.net apps through Mono.  When you say "require IIS support", are you being literal or are you assuming asp.net == IIS (which it doesn't)?  Because it is also possible (but rare) for an asp.net app to depend on IIS extensions.

Comment: Based on your description, you should switch to host on IIS and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not is possible run IIS over linux, you can use [kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) with netCore ,because IIS not is cross plataform, many applications that run "net framework" you can migrate to "net standard" , one option is install "[docker windows machine iis](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/)" but only run in windows machines